# Webpack alias for src folder in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I would like to use absolute imports to import any file relative to the root `src` directory. This is my folder structure:

```
example/
┣ public/
┃ ┣ index.html
┣ src/
┃ ┣ components/
┃ ┣ ┣ App.css
┃ ┣ ┣ App.js
┃ ┣ ┗ Todo.js
┃ ┣ api.js
┃ ┣ history.js
┃ ┗ index.js
┣ craco.config.js
┣ jsconfig.json
```

And here is my config

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
};
```

`import Todo from "src/components/Todo"`

But I get this error.

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'src/components/Todo' in 'C:\_MyFiles\Programming\example\src\components'`

---

However if I change the config and import to reference a subfolder under src like this it works...

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
    },
  },
};
```

`import Todo from "components/Todo"`

---

How can I get the 1st variation working, so the imports reference the src folder instead of its subfolders?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [path.resolve('./src'), path.resolve('./node_modules')],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

This will create an alias for all the subdirectories in your `src` and `node_modules` folders as well as your `src` folder itself.
So you'll be able to use

`Import App from 'components/App'`

and

`Import history from 'history'`